# Unity animator exit time lags the next state of the animator

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I am trying to make a game where the player moves around as a knight and can kill his enemies with his sword. I have begun working on the animations, but something isn't working quite right now. I have two attack animations, one is the regular slash and the other one is the backhand slash. I want the animations to work with exit time when they flow to each other. So 70% of the regular slash should be finished when the parameter to go to the backhand slash becomes true and from that point, the transition may happen. However, the transition starts to bug when the boolean parameter becomes true after the animation has played over 70%. The animations entirely stop for a second and then continue correctly. In [this video](https://youtu.be/SfiGTn-iUAc) you can see what is happening. So with that, my question is: Why does it stop with the animations for a moment before continuing when it has played over 70%? This project is in 3d by the way.